# In Wix can an advertised shortcut use the icon from a systems file association?

Tags: wix, icons, shortcut, file-association, advertised-shortcut

A question is about Wix and setting the icon of an advertised shortcut:

If your installer contains a manual, or document in say .pdf format and you want to create a shortcut to the PDF file. Is it possible to use an icon for the shortcut based on the systems file associations?

e.g. User has Adobe reader, the shortcut gets adobe pdf icon.
     User has Foxit/Other reader, the shortcut gets that program icon instead. etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand the installer magic, this is not possible. This has nothing to do with Wix but is a general MSI behaviour. Thus you would need to use un-advertised shortcuts to display the user's icon for PDF files.